# Scrapy database pipeline checkin after inserting items

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

In a Scrapy project, I scrape a bunch of "cases". For each case, I scrape several items, and insert into db. After each case is done, I want to mark that case as "checked in" in the db, indicating that all of the items for that case are complete.

So I made a `Checkin` item `{'checked_in': datetime.utcnow()}` for each case I produce a list of the form

`[Request(...), Request(...), Request(...), Checkin]`

However, returning that list to Scrapy causes it to insert the Checkin into the db before it has finished collecting all of the Request objects. The checkin occurs before any of the Requests are inserted.

Instead, I want a way to write it so that for each case, the pipeline won't insert a checkin object until after all of the results of the requests for that case are inserted into the db.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the whole strucutre? Is it one spider run per case? what's the table structure?

Comment: Maybe this http://scrapy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/signals.html#scrapy.signals.spider_closed can help you.

Comment: Do you want to INSERT item only all 3 Requests are completed? Also post some code.